# Reading one collection within another, whereby the respective documents were generated according to a random number

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

How can I read all objects within another collection (nested)? The documents were created with a random number (UUID).

**USER(Collection)->UUID(Doc)-->OBJECTS(Collection)->UUID(doc)->Object**

```
    db.collection("USER").document(//RANDOM UUID).collection("Objekte").get().addOnSuccessListener{ result->
        listHouses = ArrayList()
        progressDialog.dismiss()
        for(document in result.documents)
        {
            val house = document.toObject(Houses::class.java)
            listHouses.add(house!!)
        }

        var viewPager2 = view?.findViewById<ViewPager2>(R.id.viewPagerHome)

        myAdapter = CustomAdapter(myCtx,listHouses)


        viewPager2?.adapter = myAdapter
    }
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Firebase Storage, Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are all separate products. Going forward, please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read the `Objekte` of a specific user, you will need to know the document ID of that user.

If you want to read the `Objekte` across all users (and even across the entire database), you can [use a collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query). Based on that documentation, it'd be something like:

```
db.collectionGroup("Objekte").get().addOnSuccessListener{ result->
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for fixing the method call @AlexMamo.  ---  It's especially impressive I made that mistake, given that I copy/pasted most of my answer from the docs. :)

Comment: You're very welcome, puf.